# Variable to structually hold directory, subdir's and files of a path

Tags: python, python-2.7, operating-system, os.walk

Ok, here is what I want to do:
I have a programm that allows customization of it's menu's by a .py that is loaded on startup. The goal is to add a new menu icon, which then opens a submenu structure that follows the folder and file structure inside a predefinded path. Inside these folder there little tools / script that can be used in the program.

I have found some recursive code that somewhat does the job, but 
it's too complicated and I want to do it on my own.
Here is a picture of a sample file tree: 
[Sample folder structrue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEsVV.png)

Like create submenu 'other', for 'other' create submenu's 'lumapictures' and 'pixelfudger, for 'lumapictures' create channels ... and so on .. **so later the submenu stucture should reflect the folder structure of the path and files in the subdir should be added as items to their corresponding submenu.**

***Here is the part I have no smart solution for:***
I need to create a variable to store every subdir (and if they exist other subdirs within this sibdir) and files possibly existing in these directories in a smart way. Later, I need to use this variable to add the submenu's for each folder (and folders within) and if there are .gizmo's in it add them to their corresponding submenu as items. To add the .gizmo's I need the correct submenu (aka folder within the path tree) and full path to it in order to add it as an item
I know about `os.listdir()` to list all folders or all the files of a given folder with `os.isdir`and through searching found out about

```
os.walk() #sample
# traverse root directory, and list directories as dirs and files as files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/mnt/WD4TB/Backups/formultiboot/nuke/gizmos"):
    print (root)
    print (dirs)
    print (files)

returns:

/mnt/WD4TB/Backups/formultiboot/nuke/gizmos
['3d', 'despill', 'edge', 'fx', 'grain', 'key', 'other']
['L_ChannelSolo_v01.gizmo']
/mnt/WD4TB/Backups/formultiboot/nuke/gizmos/3d
[]
[]
/mnt/WD4TB/Backups/formultiboot/nuke/gizmos/despill
[]
['DespillMadness.gizmo', 'L_Despill_v05.gizmo']
/mnt/WD4TB/Backups/formultiboot/nuke/gizmos/edge
[]
[]
/mnt/WD4TB/Backups/formultiboot/nuke/gizmos/fx
[]
['expoglow.gizmo']
/mnt/WD4TB/Backups/formultiboot/nuke/gizmos/grain
[]
['L_Grain_v05.gizmo']
/mnt/WD4TB/Backups/formultiboot/nuke/gizmos/key
[]
[]
/mnt/WD4TB/Backups/formultiboot/nuke/gizmos/other
['lumapictures', 'pixelfudger']
[]
/mnt/WD4TB/Backups/formultiboot/nuke/gizmos/other/lumapictures
['Channel']
['L_ChannelSolo_v01.gizmo']
/mnt/WD4TB/Backups/formultiboot/nuke/gizmos/other/lumapictures/Channel
[]
['L_ChannelSolo_v01.gizmo']
/mnt/WD4TB/Backups/formultiboot/nuke/gizmos/other/pixelfudger
[]
['pixelfudger.py', 'PxF_Bandpass.gizmo', 'PxF_Bandpass.png', 'PxF_ChromaBlur.gizmo', 'PxF_ChromaBlur.png', 'PxF_Distort.gizmo']
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stores the location of every subdir and it's contents in a smart way"? What's the location of a subdir? What do you consider a "smart way" to access it? What does/is the "submenu stucture" and how exactly is it relevant? How will things be added to it? As it stands, I think your question is way too vague to be answered.

Comment: I edited it to make it a little clearer. Sorry, this is the best way I can to describe my case.

Comment: Well, that helps a little, but still isn't enough in my opinion. That said, a computer's file-system is fundamentally a tree structure and code that deals with them is often recursive (which usually simplifies the code, not make it more complicated). One approach would be to use [nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793708/how-to-store-a-directory-structure-from-an-ftp-site). A more general solution might be to create a `Node` class that keeps track of the information at each level include some sort of references to its sibling  `Node`s if any (and maybe even its parent).